# How to track login locations of admin/staff in django website

Tags: python, django

I have a django site,

1.where I need to create some staff users to login and access/view models.

2.But same time I want to track login locations of staff and even admin.

3.I there any proper django module or third party api to do this.

Comment: Do you want to store the IP address's location as part of the logs?

Comment: yeah, something like that and even IP addresses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some middleware and the GIS contrib app, which provides a wrapper for [geoip lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/).

Creating a simple table to log your extra details, and then use something like the following:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
from logger.models import Log # your simple Log model

def get_ip(request):
   xff = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
   if xff:
      return xff.split(',')[0]
   return request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

class UserLocationLoggerMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user and request.user.is_superuser:
            # Only log requests for superusers,
            # you can control this by adding a setting
            # to track other user types
            ip = get_ip(request)
            g = GeoIP()
            lat,long = g.lat_lon(ip)
            Log.objects.create(request.user, ip, lat, long)
```

Consult the [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) on how to setup and configure custom middleware.