# Error while setting up geoip for my site "GeoIP path must be a valid file or directory"

Tags: python, django

For my django app I am trying to store log of login location by amdin.

I created a middleware and trying use from "django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP" to get the latitude and longitude values of geo locations.

But getting error something like:

**GeoIPException at /admin/**

GeoIP path must be a valid file or directory.

code: **trackware.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
from core.models import Log # your simple Log model

def get_ip(request):
   xff = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
   if xff:
      return xff.split(',')[0]
   return request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

class UserLocationLoggerMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user and request.user.is_superuser:
            # Only log requests for superusers,
            # you can control this by adding a setting
            # to track other user types
            ip = get_ip(request)
            g = GeoIP()
            lat,long = g.lat_lon(ip)
            Log.objects.create(request.user, ip, lat, long)
```

changes that I made in **settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

#custom middleware
    'smartDNA.trackware.UserLocationLoggerMiddleware',
)

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')
```

**models.py:**

```
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(verbose_name="User",max_length=32)
    ip=models.IPAddressField(verbose_name="IP")
    lat= models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Lat",max_digits=10,decimal_places=1)
    long= models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Long",max_digits=10,decimal_places=1)
```

register model in **admin.py:**

```
admin.site.register(Log)
```

What is the mistake that I am doing and solution please....

Comment: You need to [accept answers to questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). In your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839269/how-to-track-login-locations-of-admin-staff-in-django-website/20839696#20839696), I explained that you need to [set up the geop ip framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/):

> In order to perform IP-based geolocation, the GeoIP object requires
>   the GeoIP C libary and either the GeoIP Country or City datasets in
>   binary format (the CSV files will not work!). **These datasets may be
>   downloaded from MaxMind. Grab the GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz and
>   GeoLiteCity.dat.gz files and unzip them in a directory corresponding
>   to what you set GEOIP_PATH with in your settings.**

Make sure you have done the above, otherwise the system does not know how to map IPs to locations.

Comment: I did that but still getting error something like Invalid GeoIP city data file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat

Comment: Where did you put the files?

Comment: /django/contrib/gis/geoip/ and same path I am giving in settings.py
GEOIP_PATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/gis/geoip"

Comment: but then I change path to GEOIP_PATH="os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')" and BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
then I am getting error: GeoIP path must be a valid file or directory.

Comment: Create a directory called `geoip` in the same folder that has `settings.py`, and put the `GeoLiteCity.dat` file in that directory. Then in your `settings.py`, set `GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')`

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem and I solved it in this way:

this is my project..

```
> root
    > app
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
    > static
    > application
    > templates
    manage.py
```

1) DOWNLOAD GeoLiteCountry and GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

2) Create a folder in root called `geoip` and Put both files inside.
**Be sure that both files are renamed GeoIPCity.dat and GeoIP.dat**

3) Specify the path in your settings file `GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')`

4) make a test

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
>>> g = GeoIP()
>>> g.city('72.14.207.99')
..
```

and if it stills not working, take a look to the `g` instance to find out the pointing location:

```
>>> print g._city_file
/home/foo/root/geoip/GeoIPCity.dat
>>> print g._country_file
/home/foo/root/geoip/GeoIP.dat
```

*In case you get an empty string, try to find the bug. Do not try
to re-assign the path by modifying the instance `g._city_file=/home/foo/Desktop/GeoIP.0.dat`,
it won't work !

Comment: For GeoIP2 is not longer needed to rename the db files, with original names is working just fine( "GeoLite2-Country.mmdb" and "GeoLite2-City.mmdb")

Answer (score 1):

I have changed this

```
GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')
```

to

```
GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and then I changed

`GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip')`
to 
`GEOIP_PATH =os.path.join('geoip')`.

Hope it helps.