# I am getting unknown geoip2 error

Tags: django, geoip

I am trying to test geoip but its not working, I did following steps:-

```
$ pip install geoip2
```

In `settings.py`

```
GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'geoip')
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'geoip2', ]
```

In terminal

```
$./manage.py shell
$ from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2
$ g = GeoIP2()
```

I got error i.e.

> **raise GeoIP2Exception('GeoIP path must be a valid file or directory.')
>   django.contrib.gis.geoip2.base.GeoIP2Exception: GeoIP path must be a valid file or directory.**

Comment: Please do a research before asking questions. This question is already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20853928/2282638

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal before asking a question I have done all step of that link but still I am getting the same error, I don't know what to do?

Comment: try printing settings.GEOIP_PATH and see if that directory exists.

Comment: your Django version ?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Django-2

Comment: See my answer with Django-2.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Can I have to create geo dir and unzip the file in it? or unzip the file in the project dir?

Comment: you can choose any directory but and mention that path in `GEOIP_PATH` in setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/):

> The GeoIP2 object is a wrapper for the MaxMind geoip2 Python library.
>   [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoip2/)
>
> In order to perform IP-based geolocation, the GeoIP2 object requires
>   the geoip2 Python library and the GeoIP Country and/or City datasets
>   in binary format (the CSV files will not work!). Grab the
>   GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz and GeoLite2-City.mmdb.gz files and unzip
>   them in a directory corresponding to the GEOIP_PATH setting.
>
> Additionally, it is recommended to install the libmaxminddb C library,
>   so that geoip2 can leverage the C library’s faster speed.

Make sure you have done above otherwise system will not work.

Comment: when I enter this `g.country('13.333.33.114')` I got this error TypeError: country() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

Comment: I think for country you have to pass domain name not the IP of that domain.

Comment: whats the issue is?

Comment: I downloaded city and country folder from https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/
I created geoip directory in the project and putted extracted city and country folder in it.
after that, I `pip install geoip2`
I added GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip') in `settings.py`

and open `./manage.py shell`
`from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2`
`g = GeoIP2()`
`a = g.country()`

but still, it's not working, no proper documentation of this topic.

Comment: use `a = g.country('google.com')` then you will get results